# How to break in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm beginner in AngularJS, especially javascript. I don't know how to break the process of $cookiStore isUndefined. Here's my app.js

```
angular.module('postLogin', ['ngCookies'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: "index.html"});
    $routeProvider.when('/success', {templateUrl: "success.html"});
})

.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $cookieStore, $http, $location) {        
        this.postForm = function() {
            var encodedString = 'username=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.inputData.username) +
                '&password=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.inputData.password);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'userauth.php',
                data: encodedString,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })

            .success(function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    if ( data.trim() === 'one') {
                        $cookieStore.put('username', 'admin');
                        window.location.href = 'success.html';
                    } else if ( data.trim() === 'two') {
                        $cookieStore.put('username', 'dika');
                        window.location.href = 'success.html';
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorMsg = "Username and password do not match.";
                    }
            })            
        }
        $scope.last = $cookieStore.get('username');
        //below is logout function in success.html
        $scope.go = function(){
        $cookieStore.remove('username');
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
        if ($location.url() !== '/' && angular.isUndefined($scope.last)) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
}]);
```

and here's my success.html

```
<html>
<h1> Success: Welcome to our website. </h1>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="postLogin" ng-controller="PostController">
{{last}}
<div class="buttons">
<input type="submit" class="button" ng-click="go()" value="click me">
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
      <title>angulrjs login page</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="main-css"/>  
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="postLogin" ng-controller="PostController as postCtrl">
      <div class="container">
         <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title text-center">Login using username & password</div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body" >
                  <form name="login" ng-submit="postCtrl.postForm()" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" required autofocus ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.username"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required ng-model="postCtrl.inputData.password"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                        ×</button>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{errorMsg}}
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="login.$invalid">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log in</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

It couldn't work. If I get rid "break", the result is index.html always looping cause $scope.last has undefined or null. How to resolve it ? And what can I do with that code in order to like an !isset in php. My basic of program language is only php. :(

Comment: data is in array format?

Comment: Angular supposed to be a SPA (single page application), so why do you redirect the user to a new page instead of loading a template into a `<div ng-view></div>` (Or similar) element?

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I don't understand with your explanation. Sorry, I'm beginner.

Comment: Read some tutorials I suggest you read [This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) for start. There are cool angular features you're missing. My suggestion is to learn about [ui-router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) which is a more robust library for handling states in angular

Answer (score 0):

So inside the check of Undefined for `$scope.last`, check if the `current page` is already `index.html` or not, you can do it by using `$location` service. so just use

```
if ($location.url() !== '/' && angular.isUndefined($scope.last)) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
}
```

**Note:** Inject the `$location` service into the `PostController`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint and check what's the `$location.url()` is fetching you!

Comment: I modified if ($location.url('success.html') && angular.isUndefined($scope.last)) { window.location.href = 'index.html'; } but it doesn't work for me :(